# How to use gsl::span with asio

Tags: c++, asio

The problem:
I cannot compile asio to use a buffer with `gsl::span`

Constraints:

- C++ Version allowed: <= C++17
- Boost allowed: No
- Microsoft GSL [4.0.0](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/tree/v4.0.0), or newer as it's available
- Asio [1.28.0](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/tree/asio-1-28-0), or newer as it's available

I'm trying to use gsl::span in my asio-based code because it keeps track of its size.
How does one construct an asio buffer given a `gsl::span`?

This does not compile:

```cpp
#include "asio/buffer.hpp"
#include <gsl/span>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<uint8_t, 12> arr{};
    auto arrBuf = asio::buffer(arr);

    gsl::span gslSpan = gsl::make_span(arr);
    auto gslSpanBuf = asio::buffer(gslSpan);
     
    return 0;
}
```

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘buffer(gsl::span<unsigned char, 18446744073709551615>&)’
```

This compiles, breaking out the data pointer and size of the `gsl::span` object.

```cpp
#include "asio/buffer.hpp"
#include <gsl/span>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<uint8_t, 12> arr{};
    auto arrBuf = asio::buffer(arr);

    gsl::span gslSpan = gsl::make_span(arr);
    auto gslSpanBuf = asio::buffer(gslSpan.data(), gslSpan.size());
     
    return 0;
}
```

Why does asio not support passing the span in as a single argument? It has both a `.data()` and `.size()`.

In the docs, it states asio 1.23.0 added support:

```
Added `buffer()` overloads for contiguous containers, such as `const gsl::span<const uint8_t>`.
```

Comment: You code works on my machine. I am running gcc version 13.1.1, gsl version 4.0.0, and asio version 1.28. I suggest to try GSL git main branch as well.